# owin google auth with mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, owin, google-plus-signin

i create a new mvc5 standard project.
I edited the Startup.Auth.cs adding:

```
 app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
 {
      ClientId = "myClientCode.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      ClientSecret = "myClientSecret"
 });
```

and web.config adding:

```
 <location path="signin-google">
     <system.web>
          <authorization>
               <allow users="*" />
          </authorization>
     </system.web>
</location>
```

I set on the google developer console the autorized javascript origins to http://localhost:58053 and the Authorized redirect URIs to http://localhost:58053/signin-google

and turned on the following google API

- BigQuery API
- Debuglet Controller API
- Google Cloud SQL
- Google Cloud Storage
- Google Cloud Storage JSON API
- Google+ API  Disable
- Identity Toolkit API

But when i select my google account, on callback in

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
```

the value of

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

is null

The callback generated by accounts.google.com is something like this:

```
 http://localhost:58053/signin-google?state=K0Q6LHytGsRTpArK9TruwwzurLNbS4JeK30LEYhMmuaH9vmh3zQslFUA0dqByxftJlCBd6NhxyK12Co-2rKjBX711-WTfUNXKajPSKmpc7PiwwqBFwrnhMvUFh6f0b9iHTO4DU0EwBBBiYEDPkpvGsc--oTjTzzqf2qcpNLjScj9Hg6Obxm8tbHBcbO5CJcDxQtMWf8bOJ6bjVihqJwJ270Ps5SGfB9IRdxqJbVlIrM&code=4/tnXrYTNPuoTdZZmT29fWCWoE63_1HEa9g0lCrOi_vo8&authuser=1&session_state=3a5578d289d23d09dac97e705ebc613f4599f92b..d2d9&prompt=none
```

and it seems to be ok

any idea about i can retrieve account data using owin?